# Aggregation result with a unique column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I performing an aggregation on a table, below is a snap shot of the Job table I am querying.

[image]

my query is similar to below. In reality the above derived table will have many more columns as results of multiple joins.

```
select Attribute   
from Job 
where Description = 'Installation' and Attribute = 'NPL' 
group by Attribute 
having sum(Cost) >= 500
```

I want to get the `JobID` of the matching records as that is unique and I can use it for further joins. How can I get the jobID's(which is PK) of the matching records.

I am not sure if its OK to do this,

```
select Attribute, JobID 
from Job 
where Description = 'Installation' and Attribute = 'NPL' 
group by Attribute, JobID  
having sum(Cost) >= 500
```

I am expecting the result like(for above scenario),

[image]

Comment: could you tell what should your output look like?

Comment: Hi Vijaykumar, I have just edited the question to add the result table I am looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping this way won't give you desired result :

```
Group by Attribute, JobID
```

with that, `JobID = 34` and `JobID = 39` will be in separate group. One of several possible ways is using `INNER JOIN` and subquery to achieve that "*expected result*" picture :

```
select j.Attribute, j.JobID   
from Job j
    inner join
        (select Attribute   
         from Job 
         where Description = 'Installation' and j.Attribute = 'NPL' 
         group by Attribute 
         having sum(Cost) >= 500) a on a.Attribute = j.Attribute
where j.Description = 'Installation' and j.Attribute = 'NPL'
```

Comment: but the Attribute is not unique so it may match up with unwanted record in other scenarios, doesn't it??

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregates with window functions so that the original rows are preserved but you can reason about the aggregate value. You need to compute the aggregate in a subquery or CTE though:

```
;With Totals as (
    select *,SUM(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Attribute) as TotalCost
    from Job
    where Description = 'Installation' and Attribute = 'NPL' 
)
select * from Totals where TotalCost > 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    SELECT 
        J.JobId,
        J.Description 
    FROM dbo.Jobs J
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            Attribute
        FROM dbo.Jobs
        GROUP BY
            Attribute
        having 
            sum(Cost) >= 500
    ) AS G
    ON J.Attribute = G.Attribute 
    where 
        J.Description = 'Installation' 
        and J.Attribute = 'NPL'
```